# JavaScript: Combining arrays to N in size

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have an array like this:

```
[ 
  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ],
  [ 'h', 'i', 'j' ],
  [ 'g' ],
  [ 'k' ],
  [ 'o', 'p' ] 
]
```

How can I create multiple arrays (that has 5 elements in total) from the input array given?

Output example:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'],
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k'],
['h', 'i', 'j', 'g', 'k'],
['h', 'i', 'j', 'o', 'p'],
```

But, the elements cannot be seperated for e.x:

```
['a', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'g']
```

The ['a'] element should be together with ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and cannot be seperated. It should use ['k'] instead because it's a single element.

Thanks!

Comment: So the right-filled values should only come from arrays with the exact or fewer number of required elements? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You've forgotten to post the code you already have for the task.

Comment: I don't understand at all how the output was generated from the input.

Comment: Yes, it should fill with fewer elements. The output is combination from the input array with maximum of 5 elements.

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear enough to support your expected output

Comment: What happens if there are no other arrays with the right number of entries? Where are the results starting with `'g'`, `'k'` and `['o', 'p']`?

Comment: There will be no array created if it's less than 5 elements. Refer to the solution made by Utkarsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go :)

```
 function combineArrays(arraysArray) {
    let combinedArraysArray = [];
    for (let i=0; i<arraysArray.length; i++) {
        for (let j=i+1; j<arraysArray.length; j++) {
            if (arraysArray[i].length + arraysArray[j].length <= 5) {
                let tempCombinedArray = arraysArray[i];
                for (let k=j; k<arraysArray.length; k++) {
                    if (tempCombinedArray.length === 5) {
                        break;
                    } else if (tempCombinedArray.length + arraysArray[k].length <= 5) {
                        tempCombinedArray = tempCombinedArray.concat(arraysArray[k]);
                    }
                }
                if (tempCombinedArray.length === 5) {
                    combinedArraysArray.push(tempCombinedArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return combinedArraysArray;
}
```

Comment: There we go! Holymoly it's been hard for the last 2 hours. Thanks man!

Comment: Will do, I'm a new user and can't vote directly (need more reputations).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
var array =[ 
  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ],
  [ 'h', 'i', 'j' ],
  [ 'g' ],
  [ 'k' ],
  [ 'o', 'p' ] 
];


let array1 = array.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b));
var newArry=[];
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
   if(i %5 ==0)
   {
      newArry.push([]);
   }   
   newArry[newArry.length -1].push(array1[i]);
}
console.log(newArry);
```

Comment: Tried it, but the array from the input cannot be seperated. For example, [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'h' ] has ['h'] on it. It should be ['g'] or ['k'] instead. ['h'] should be together with ['h', 'i', 'j']

Comment: I tried running your code, and it outputs [ [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'h' ],
  [ 'i', 'j', 'g', 'k', 'o' ],
  [ 'p' ] ]. In the first one, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'h'] has ['h'] element on it. The ['h'] element should be together with [ 'h', 'i', 'j' ] and cannot be seperated. It should use ['g'] or ['k'] instead because it's a single element.

Comment: So it should output [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'] and [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'k']